# Convert all multiline LONGTEXT columns to JSON columns

Tags: mysql, sql, json, type-conversion

**SUMMARY:**
Conducting a Database migration and I'm trying to move 10k worth of LONGTEXT COLUMNS full of paragraphs with line breaks into a new DB TABLE COLUMN of JSON datatype.

**SPECS:**
MYSQL v5.7 and using InnoDB Engine (So there are some limits on JSON functionality.)

EXAMPLE TABLE `OLD_DB_TAB` COLUMN `text_body`:

```sql
ID     text_body 
1      This is an intro paragraph. Here are some words.

       And a second paragraph. More words.

2      This is another column value with multiline strings. Here are some 
       words.

       Look, another paragraph in this same column. More words. 
       Even a third paragraph!

3      And so on ...
```

EXAMPLE TABLE `NEW_DB_TAB` COLUMN `json_text_body`:

```sql
ID     json_text_body 
1      {"body": [{"insert": "This is an intro paragraph. Here are some 
       words.\nAnd a second paragraph. More words.\n\n"}]}

2      {"body": [{"insert": "This is another column value with multiline 
       strings.\nHere are some words.\nLook, another paragraph in this 
       same column.\nMore words.\nEven a third paragraph!\n\n"}]}

3      {"body": [{"insert": "And so on ...\n\n"}]}
```

My latest attempt for an SQL code solution has failed and the error says "Subquery returns more than 1 row":

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT `text_body` FROM `OLD_DB`) AS JSON)
```

**How can I:**
Convert all LONGTEXT columns to JSON columns? In the example tables posted here, convert OLD_DB.text_body to a JSON datatype in NEW_DB.json_text_body. Is there an SQL code solution?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for. something loke that text_boy
[{"fieldA": "This is an intro paragraph. Here are some words.\n\nAnd a second paragraph. More words."}, {"fieldA": "This is another column value with multiline strings. Here are some words."}, {"fieldA": "Look, another paragraph in this same column. More words.\nEven a third paragraph!\nAnd so on ..."}]

Comment: Sorry if my post is unclear, I'm looking for a way to convert TEXT fields into JSON fields. The text has multiple line breaks in it. I have had no luck so far...

Comment: I updated the duplicated table examples in my original question, sorry for the confusion. Should be accurate now for a json result. Your aggregation function has blown me away, i really need to learn more intricacies in mysql. I am trying it out now, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a start, where the paragraphs are put into there own rows and then i build a json  set.
Of course you have to change it to fit your data

So lets start
With this Database as Base

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ID` int, `text_body` text)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`ID`, `text_body`)
VALUES
    (1, 'This is an intro paragraph. Here are some words.\n\nAnd a second paragraph. More words.'),
    (2, 'This is another column value with multiline strings. Here are some words.'),
    (3, 'Look, another paragraph in this same column. More words.\nEven a third paragraph!\nAnd so on ...')

;
```

You get with this Select statement

```
Select
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("text_body", `part`,"ID",`ID` )) text_body
FROM
(
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.text_body, '\n', N.n + 1)
    , '\n', -1
   ) AS part
   ,p.ID
FROM (SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS a
   CROSS JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS b
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := -1) AS I
   WHERE @n < 1000) N 
  CROSS JOIN  table1 p
    WHERE 
      N.n <= (LENGTH(p.text_body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.text_body, '\n', ''))) 
)t1;
```

You get  this result

```
[{"ID": 1, "text_body": "This is an intro paragraph. Here are some words."},
 {"ID": 2, "text_body": "This is another column value with multiline strings. Here are some words."},
  {"ID": 3, "text_body": "Look, another paragraph in this same column. More words."},
  {"ID": 1, "text_body": "And a second paragraph. More words."},
  {"ID": 3, "text_body": "Even a third paragraph!"}
   , {"ID": 3, "text_body": "And so on ..."}]
```

So this works with mysql 5,7 band 8.x, before that there are no json fuctions that could do that and you have to build it by hand with concat. But the inner Select works almost perfectly as it is, only \n\n doesn't work for now.

[Here is the whole thing at dbfiddle to play with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=609f544028c9cf90fa5b9cf35d85d8c6)